# Error Installing PythonMagick Under OSX Lion

Tags: python, imagemagick, osx-lion, pythonmagick

Has anyone here on StackOverflow been able to get PythonMagick successfully installed on a Mac computer running Lion? I've downloaded the PythonMagick source and installed all of the dependencies specified. However, when I run "./configure", "make" and "make install" it exits with an "error 1". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thank you,

L.

Comment: Error 666: Please post full error messages

Comment: Here is the full error message:
make[1]: *** [libpymagick_la-_DrawableFillRule.lo] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Comment: Full means all the related logs. Error 1 can mean anything, so it is not possible to help you based on this information.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: yes, people have been able to get PythonMagick to work.

You'll need to include more information about the error for us to help you.

One common issue is [failing to install ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276858/installing-pythonmagick/13279009#13279009).

Another is [modifying the `__init__`.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954568/problems-detecting-pythonmagick-after-install-mac-osx) seems to be a somewhat common problem.