# Problems detecting PythonMagick after install Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, import, imagemagick, pythonmagick

I followed the instructions at https://gist.github.com/2778301 but when I try to do `import PythonMagick` I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "PythonMagick/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _PythonMagick
ImportError: cannot import name _PythonMagick
```

The PythonMagick.so is in my python2.7 site-packages.

EDIT:
I solved this problem by copying from where `make install` installed PythonMagick `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PythonMagick` to where Python actually looks on a OS X Lion, `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

Answer (score 2):

There's an answer to your question on [the link](https://gist.github.com/2778301) you provided:

This can be fixed by changing the first line of `__init__.py` in PythonMagick, which is usually found in the `site-packages` directory, for instance,

```
python2.7/site-packages/PythonMagick
```

Try changing:

```
from . import _PythonMagick
```

to

```
import _PythonMagick
```

Comment: Importing this module this way does not work for me and I am using Python 3.74