# Installing PythonMagick

Tags: python, pythonmagick

I cannot seem to find any instructions on how to install PythonMagick on a Mac. I've tried the instructions given on this link https://gist.github.com/2778301, but am getting following error:

"No package 'MagickCore' found"

Please help?

Comment: What instruction are you getting an error on? What's the exact nature of the error? Also, you can probably try instructions from other sites, like http://www.geero.net/2011/03/install-pythonmagick-mac-os-x.html.

Comment: Perhaps [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954568/problems-detecting-pythonmagick-after-install-mac-osx) might help? Looks like a common problem. See also this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304944/error-installing-pythonmagick-under-osx-lion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having googled around a bit, it appears that you may need to install the ImageMagick package of which "MagickCore" is a component. It looks like you can download an installer for the Mac here: http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/.

If you've already installed ImageMagick, you'll likely need to set a couple environmental variables to point to the installation.

You'll need to include additional information about the error message (just post the full error message) and your Python version for more help.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed boost-python and boost-python-devel? If not, you can use yum to install them. When you have done so, open `~/.bash_profile` and add:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Close it and source `.bash_profile` (or start a new `bash`).